# Lexer Parser confusion

Tags: design-patterns, naming-conventions

I am developing a new tool. This tool take a XML file and create several user interface.

I really need to organism my code. To do that I use namespace. The path between namespace made by the input file looks like that.

> XML >> Parser(or Lexer) >> Token tree >> generator >> User Interface

The problem is that's I don't understand the difference between Lexer and Parser.

```
protected function __construct(\SimpleXMLElement $xml, string $xmlFileName,
                               AbstractContainer $container) {

    // Link the container with its child
    $this->container = $container;

    // Initialize the class attributes
    $this->name = $xml->attributes()["name"];
    //...
}
```

This code represent a little part of my constructor. But where is the part of lexer and where is the part of parser ??

Sorry for my English, I am learning it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I understand much of your question, but a lexer is a process that converts a sequence of *characters* to tokens. That's evidently already been done by the xml api you're using.

So there won't be no lexer in your code; if you want to separate the interpretation of your xml format in several layers you're free to do it in the way you see most fit.